# Microsoft Access SQL Statement to find unique values of one field when comparing two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

This shouldn't be too difficult but I am a beginner to SQL.

I have two tables, both with many fields, but the important thing is that they both have a field called CODE. This field, CODE, has numbers but is of datatype Text.

Table1 contains "tons" of CODE values. Table2 contains "a moderate amount" of CODE values. It is important to note that if a CODE value is found in Table2, it is definitely in Table1.

What I would like to do is create a query that creates a table that lists out all of the CODE values that are in Table1 AND not in Table2.

Comment: For people who land here by a search: Many database support a `MINUS` or `EXCEPT` clause on `SELECT` that works for this query. Access 2007 (and as far as I know, subsequent) does _not_.

Comment: What MS Access has had for many versions is a Find Mismatched Query Wizard. Why not try it?

Comment: @Jordan - did any of these answers help you?  If so, please accept the one that helped you so that other users know your question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Table1.CODE
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CODE = Table2.CODE
WHERE Table2.CODE IS NULL
```

And as pointed out, if you want to add it to a brand new table instead of simply querying the results, use `SELECT ... INTO`:

```
SELECT Table1.CODE
INTO Table3
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CODE = Table2.CODE
WHERE Table2.CODE IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes.  The Unmatched Query Wizard will help you come up with the syntax as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   t1.code
INTO
   new_table
FROM
   table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   table2 t2
ON
   t1.code = t2.code
WHERE 
   t2.code is null
```

Try that please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...edited so a new table with the values is created

```
SELECT T1.Code
  INTO new_table
  FROM Table1 T1
 wHERE T1.Code NOT IN (SELECT T2.Code
                         FROM Table1 T2)
```

You could use `LEFT JOIN` too but I prefer `NOT IN`

Comment: Good one, I really like SELECT's within WHERE's, just add INTO since he wants a new table to be created.